# How to get images after 503 redirection?

Tags: .htaccess

I need some help !
Indeed I've done a redirection for maintenance on my server but images don't show up.

**To explain the problem here is how the file are organized :**

```
- assets
       - css
       - fonts
       - img
         - slider
            - different images
       - js
 -  maintenance.html
 -  maintenance.enable
 - .htaccess
```

**So here's my .htacces :**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.html -f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.enable -f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !maintenance.html
RewriteRule ^.*$ /maintenance.html [R=503,L]
ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
```

I don't undestand why **maintenance.html** can't access to his dependences which are located in assets ...

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to close this:
Here was the solution.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.html -f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.enable -f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets #Solution

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !maintenance.html
RewriteRule ^.*$ /maintenance.html [R=503,L]
ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
```